# How to get Data from a simple List

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get data from a database but there's none (table is empty) and I want that. But when I do this `value="<%=settingsList.get(0).getGitlabUrl()%>">` ***I want to get null or ""***. If I run this code it crashes because index 0 doesn't exist. **How can I get null if there's nothing on the list??**

```
String user = session.getAttribute("loggedUser").toString();
SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
Session hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
List settings = null;
try {
    tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "FROM Settings s WHERE s.user= :user";
    Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("user", user);
    List<Settings> settingsList = query.list();

<label for="link" class="form-control-label">GitLab Url</label>
<input class="form-control" id="link" name="gitlabUrl" type="text" value="<%=settingsList.get(0).getGitlabUrl()%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test whether the list is empty, you can try:
`<%=settingsList.isEmpty() ? "" : settingsList.get(0).getGitlabUrl()%>`
or something equivalent depending on the definition of your list.

Comment: I dont want to check if list is empty otherwise I would just do if size > 0. I want to get null in all fields. I don't really want to do that code for all the fields.

Comment: Get null in all fields? Which fields? What is the link with calling a method on the first element of a list possibly empty?

Comment: This is supposed to show the data from a table. But before I insert data to a table I need to load the page to insert the data. That's why I want to load the page will null values.

Comment: fixed: Settings setting = (Settings) query.uniqueResult();
                                if(setting == null)
                                {
                                    setting = new Settings();
                                }

Comment: but now I get null on the fields instead of ""